# How to remove Bootstrap 3 class row bottom white border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, sticky-footer

how can I do this?

Here is the page what I`m creating

```
http://investbitcoins.tk/login/en
```

After that I added sticky footer on the page which does not have enough height from the the content. Under the row class appeared white line

This is an print-screen of the page and I add red lines where is the problem

```
http://s017.radikal.ru/i421/1505/96/968a987c418a.png
```

And if you can see the other page
example:

```
http://investbitcoins.tk/register/en
```

here is nothing like that.

I do not understand what to do. I am searching and searching but Still nothing found. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to remove this line from your `element.css` line 9-11

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(3,3,2,.65), 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.9), inset 0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(3,3,2,.65), 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.9), inset 0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(3,3,2,.65), 0 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.9), inset 0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
```